# Extracting Items from json results using php (items showing up more than once)

Tags: php, json, youtube-data-api

I'm currently trying to extract the title and video id from a playlist I've created on youtube.

I'm using `youtube api v3` to get the playlist results back in json format.

I can extract the information I need, but for some reason the results are not coming back as expected.

For example, I have three videos on this playlist as a test, when I look at the json results it also lists 3 items.

However, when I list the items with the below code, the first 2 items are listed 4 times in a row each and the last item is listed once.

P.S I left out the `$url` because it wasn't the cause of my problem.

```
$result77 = file_get_contents($url);
$YTapiJSON = json_decode($result77, TRUE);
foreach ($YTapiJSON['items'] as $key){
    foreach ($key as $key2) {
        foreach ($key2 as $key3) { 
            $title = $key2['title'];
            $key4 = $key2['resourceId']['videoId'];
        }
        if(!empty($key4)) {
            echo $title. "Added " .$key4. "<br>";
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: no idea how to "Tab" my code properly. as you can probably work out, I'm pretty new to posting on here and still trying to figure out how to show the code and everything that I need to ask the question.

Comment: Ive updated my first post with more information that will hopefully help.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than so many foreach loops, I'd use a couple of `array_column()` calls like this: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/05ba0fa4b6767a82a990704f32d3d016355a6564))

```
$titles=array_column(array_column(json_decode($json,true)['items'],'snippet'),'title');
var_export($titles);
```

First convert the json into an array, then access the `items` subarray, then collect the `snippet` subarrays, then collect the `title` values from that.

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'test title 1',
  1 => 'test title 2',
  2 => 'test title 3',
)
```

---

If you want `title` and `videoId`, then you could use this instead:

```
$snippets=array_column(json_decode($json,true)['items'],'snippet');
foreach($snippets as $a){
    echo $a['title'],(!empty($a['resourceId']['videoId'])?" Added: {$a['resourceId']['videoId']}":''),"\n";
}
```

Here is a [Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/010f0e228eb9ff4bfe57cddcf0f999eb1d0a9c3f) where I've modified the second video's videoId (made it empty) for effect.

Output:

```
test title 1 Added: Da8-QfGemgo
test title 2
test title 3 Added: 5lvkwZZZmGc
```

Comment: this accomplishes exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: @Born2DoubleUp Please read this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work